# Are the Istari speaking the langauge of Eru Iluvatar when speaking spells?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Eru Illuvatar and the Ainur express 'magic,' or their godly powers, through the usage of song and words.  Is the magic we see in Middle-Earth a translation of Eru's language, or is it vaguely something else that is entirely unexplained?

Update with examples of spoken spells

- Arwen’s spell at the ford of the Bruinen was in Sindarin: “Waters of
  the Misty Mountains / listen to the great word; / flow waters of
  Loudwater / against the Ringwraiths!” Of course, this wasn’t part of
  the book, so it was designed specifically for the movie. I’m assuming
  the choice to use Sindarin was meant to reflect Arwen’s largely
  Sindarin heritage.
- Elrond’s healing “spell” for Frodo (if you
  consider that a spell) was also in Sindarin: “Frodo, hear my voice,
  come back to [the] light.”
- In the movie, Saruman uses a spell to
  create a storm on Caradhras. In Quenya, he says: “Wake up cruel
  Redhorn! May your blood-stained horn shall fall upon the
  enemy-heads.”
- Gandalf’s answering spell on Caradhras was in Sindarin:
  “Sleep Caradhras, be still, lie still, hold [your] wrath.” Why they
  chose to have Saruman speaking in Quenya, and Gandalf in Sindarin, I
  don’t know. Neither of these spells appear in the books.
- Gandalf does
  use a spell on Caradhras, and after coming back down the mountain in
  the books to start a fire. He says “Fire for saving us!” and later
  uses it again, adding “Fire against the wolf-host!” Both spells are
  in Sindarin.
- Gandalf uses two spells when trying to open the Doors of
  Durin. One is in Quenya (“Gate of Elves listen to my word, Threshold
  of Dwarves!”), and another in Sindarin (“Gate of the Elves open now
  for me. Doorway of the Dwarf-folk listen to the word of my tongue.”)
  The Sindarin spell was part of the book, and it’s mentioned that he
  said “other spells”, though the exact languages aren’t specified.
- In Shelob’s lair, Frodo calls out in Quenya, saying “Hail Eärendil
  brightest of the Stars!” This might be considered a spell, since it
  certainly had a sort of “magical” effect.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add some references to be clear what you're talking about?  Which uses of magic in particular?  (Presumably something the Istari do?)  I'm also not sure you can talk about Eru's influences as "magic;" would you say that the Christian God does "magic?"

Comment: Hello, I updated the question with some examples.  'Magic,' is in quotations to signify that 'magic' is not really the correct term, but the term that illustrates what I'm referring to.

Comment: We're you inspired by https://youtu.be/oU0saLv-2LQ, by any chance? If not, you may enjoy that series of videos :-)

Comment: Gah, "Were", not "We're".

Answer (score 1):

Answered prior to the edit of the question.

We don't know. All we know about the Valar, and their language, is what they've explained to the Elves, reported by them in Quenya -- explained in terms the Elves can understand.

From the often-reliable Tolkien Gateway: [Translations from the Elvish](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Translations_from_the_Elvish)

We know it as [The Silmarillion](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Silmarillion), as published and then more specifically and temporally from [HoMe](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_History_of_Middle-earth).

Comment: Technically, we know a smattering of the *language* of the Valar, but it's not clear that's something they brought with them to Eä. I imagine there was no need for spoken language outside of Eä, and the Valar simply decided to have *a* language (like what they saw the Children of Eru would speak) once they chose similar bodies for themselves.

Comment: The dialog between Aragorn and the Master of the Houses of Healing gives the name of "kingsfoil" in "Valinorian", but doe not say that is the "language of Eru"

Comment: @chepner One of the HoME works talks about various languages attributed to individual Valar (more likely their Maia followers). In this framework, Quenya was descended from "Oromëan" since it was Oromë who first came across the Elves at Cuiviénen and presumably taught them to speak.

Comment: @DavidSiegel The "Valinorean" of the herb-master is Quenya (https://www.elfdict.com/w/asea_aranion?include_old=1), not [Valarin](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Valian).

Comment: @Spencer That's one of the earlier abandoned ideas. Later texts do not agree with it.